# Tangent Line to the Inverse of a 5th Degree Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function, tangent-line

So I'm in Calculus I so figuring the inverse of a 5th degree function is beyond my ken. I need to find the slope of the tangent line to its inverse function.
[image: f(x) = x^5 + 3x^3 − 4x − 8]

I have noticed that F(x) = -8 when x = 0, so f^-1(-8) should be 0. But I'm not sure where to go with that information.

Thanks for your guidance.

Update: Fixed typo

Comment: Assuming the inverse exists, the slope (derivative) of the inverse is the reciprocal of the slope of the original function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Comment: That's cool, how do you find the slope of x^5+3x^3-4x-8?

Comment: Oh, the reciprocal of the derivative of the original function. I get it now.